# Deploying Django - Most static files are appearing except images

Tags: python, django, deployment, amazon-s3

Most of my static files on my newly deployed Django website are working (CSS), but not the images. All the images are broken links for some reason and I cannot figure out why. I am serving my static files via Amazon AWS S3.

I believe all my settings are configured correctly as the collectstatic command works (and the  css styling sheets are up on the web). What could be the problem?

Comment: Please provide more details. What paths are the images trying to request. What is the configuration for static/media files. Can you verify that the images have been uploaded to S3, for instance via the S3 browser? Are the links generated in the templates the correct links. etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably impossible to give an accurate assessment with the limited info on your setup.  If your css files are working what folder are they sitting in on your server?

Why not have images folder in the same directory and set that directory to your MEDIA_URL in your settings.py file?

In your browser check your images full path and compare that to your CSS files, where are they pointing, do you have a directory on your server where they are supposed to be?  are you receiving an access denied if you try to directly put in that image url into your browser?